# reverse foreign key join - select from two tables

Tags: django, django-models

I have long looked for an answer to this question, and have yet to find one. Hopefully s/o can help me out.

I have two models:

```
class UsedEverywhere(models.Model):
    fk_OtherThing = models.ForeignKey(OtherThing)
    ...(many more fks)

class NewThing(models.Model):
    fk_UsedEverywhere(UsedEverywhere)
    newThingMember = models.IntegerField()
```

I simply want to join those two tables. It would be quite easy if I could just do something like

```
x = NewThing.objects.get()
x.fk_UsedEverwhere.fk_OtherThing ...
```

the problem is, the UsedEverywhere models is already used in many many places throughout my code base, and if i want to put 'NewThing' as the 'parent' of UsedEverywhere, I will have to update lots and lots of code so existing code that has something like:

```
x = x.filter(fk_OtherThing=val)
```

would have to change to

```
x = x.filter(fk_UsedEverywhere.fk_OtherThing=val)
```

and I am trying to avoid that. My SQL relationship are all set up exactly how I want them, i do not want to give UsedEverywhere a column for NewThing.

I want to do something like:

```
x = UsedEverywhere.objects.join(NewThing.fk_UsedEverywhere)
member = x.newThingMember
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

Use a OneToOneField not a foreign key field https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/

As you can see in their examples,  you can do something like

```
x = UsedEverywhere.objects.get(pk=1)
x.NewThing...
```